# Read minidump file Windown 7

Tags: virtualbox, bsod

I am having troubles after installing VirtualBox with a BSOD on startup and was wondering how to view the minidump file that is created.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/476394/how-to-use-windows-mini-dump-files

Comment: Thanks, would you by any chance know why VirtualBox would cause DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL with ndid.sys?

Comment: That's what the post I linked to is for.

Comment: zip and upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\minidump.