# Windows 7 BSOD 0x7A after every 1-2 hour

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, bsod

My computer is BSOD'ing after every 1-2 hour. It is doing BSOD randomly. When I check for solutions no solution came up. Even the xml file is not readable.

- I'll try to take an screenshot of the BSOD screen and post here. Is there a way to read that Dump file?
- I am using a laptop so I can't check the power, cables etc.

  ```
  Problem signature:
        Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
        OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
        Locale ID:    1033

  Additional information about the problem:
    BCCode:   7a
    BCP1: C04C9198
    BCP2: C0000185
    BCP3: 6232F8C0
    BCP4: 99233FC8
    OS Version:   6_1_7601
    Service Pack: 1_0
    Product:  256_1

  Files that help describe the problem:
    C:\Windows\Minidump\112614-19812-01.dmp
    C:\Users\Alam\AppData\Local\temp\WER-130214-0.sysdata.xml

  Read our privacy statement online:
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

  If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
    C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
  ```

Details from Who Crashed software:

```
On Tue 11/25/2014 11:38:02 PM GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\112614-19812-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntkrnlpa.exe (nt+0xDEBFC) 
Bugcheck code: 0x7A (0xFFFFFFFFC04C9198, 0xFFFFFFFFC0000185, 0x6232F8C0, 0xFFFFFFFF99233FC8)
Error: KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: This bug check indicates that the requested page of kernel data from the paging file could not be read into memory. 
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.
```

Image from Blue Screen View software
[image: Image from Blue Screen View software]

Comment: A program like `BlueScreenViewer` allows you to determine which drivers were loaded when the system crashed we need that information.

Comment: @VikasGupta, This is enough iformation. Stopcode is 0x7a: KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR; with BCP2 meaning: STATUS_IO_DEVICE_ERROR, indicates improper termination or defective cabling on SCSI devices or that two devices are trying to use the same IRQ.

Comment: You should post more examples of these BSOD reports. We might be able to better diagnose your problem with the additional information. If you have a report that specifies 0xC000009C or 0xC000016A for BCP2, we can say for sure your hard disk is bad.

Comment: Looks like hard disk problem. Please open [Windows Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7), there are system logs. Look for Errors and paste them here if you can.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/476420/10165 I tend to favour whocrashed and bluescreenview for dump analysis.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Image from Blue Screen View is already added. I'll try the other software too.

Comment: @LPChip So its an IRQ conflict then

Comment: @Virusboy The BSoD is caused by an IRQ conflict, but the conflict itself is likely to happen due to a bad cable or connection.

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Stop 0x7A, BCP2 0xC0000185 means **you may have a hard disk problem**—the system was unable to communicate with the disk. Make sure all cables are properly seated. If that doesn't solve the problem, examine the hard disk's SMART information using a program such as [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html). The SMART status may indicate that you need to replace the hard disk.

The non-readability of the XML file only reinforces the possibility of a disk issue—the system may not have been able to write the file to disk.

---

All of the BSODs you've listed have 0xC0000185 for parameter 2. See if you can open up the laptop and check if the hard drive is firmly attached, and reseat it if possible. You should also post SMART information and run self-tests on the drive to see if there are any issues. Try running a disk check (`CHKDSK`) with surface scan to determine if there are any bad sectors.

Comment: +1 and I want to add: It might be also SATA connector or cable problem. Some SATA cables are really low quality and loose connectivity.

Comment: @DragonLord I'll update you after running those tests.

Comment: DOS based tools or tools with their own environment say Spinrite will really help.  This will allow you to eliminate a windows problem, if you crash while in one of those tools, then you know its a hardware problem.

Answer (score -1):

I will appreciate if you could provide me detailed information about your computer specifications. Anyways, based on your query the following solutions will be definitely helpful for you:

Check problems with your hard disk, i.e. disk read/ write issues that prevent retrieving/ accessing data in the system files.

1. Double click Computer icon.
2. Right click a partition.
3. Select Properties.
4. Click Tools -> Check Now.

Another thing, check for memory issues as below:

1. Click Start, type "memory" in the Search Box.
2. Open the "Windows Memory Diagnostic".
3. Click "Restart now and check for problems".

Adjust the Paging File Size again. Set the most appropriate Paging File size as shown below. Then run ActiveX/ DLL registration scan with the help of Reginout software. Resolve any internal conflicts found.

1. Right click the Computer icon on your desktop.
2. Select Properties from the context menu.
3. Click “Advanced system settings” link.
4. System Properties dialog will be displayed.
5. Click Settings (Performance) -> Advanced.
6. Click Change (Virtual Memory).
7. Uncheck the box named “Automatically manage the paging file size for all drives”.
8. Select the system drive, usually drive C:\
9. Select “Custom size” option.
10. Increase the current paging file size, and then click Set button.
11. Click OK | OK | OK.
12. Restart your computer for the changes to take effects.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score -1):

Alam

Without the actual crash logs (called DMP files) it is just a guess. **[This wiki](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/blue-screen-of-death-bsod/1939df35-283f-4830-a4dd-e95ee5d8669d)** will show you how to find and upload the DMP files for analysis

Comment: How about putting the content from the website into your answer.  If that article were to be moved as often happens with Microsoft support articles its common for the old link to stop working entirely